# How can we compare two plots?

Tags: pdf, plot

Suppose we have two similar plots.

1. Plot1 (already published in a paper)
2. Plot2 (calculated by using any software)

My question is: How can I compare my calculated plot (pdf, png, jpeg, etc) with the plot in the paper.
Thank You

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, there is currently no software that would enable you to re-convert images into their nominal data.

However, it's not that hard to write a piece of code that does it.

Here are the steps (at a high level):

1. extract the images from the pdf document (use iText)
2. separate out those images that look like a plot. You can train a neural network to do this, or you can simply look for images that contain a lot of white (assuming that's the background) and have some straight lines in black (assuming that's the foreground). Or do this step manually.
3. Once you have the image(s), extract axis information. I'll assume a simple lineplot. Extract the minimal x and y value, and the maximum x and y value.
4. separate out the colors of the lines in your lineplot, and get their exact pixel coordinates. Then, using the axis information, scale them back to their original datapoint.
5. apply some kind of smoothing algorithm. E.g. Savitzky-Golay
6. If you ever use this data in another paper, please mention that you gathered this data by approximation of their graph. Make it clear you did not use the original source data.

Reading material:

- https://developers.itextpdf.com/examples
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Savitzky%E2%80%93Golay_filter
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/index.html